# Display latest comments on page with pagination

Tags: pages, comments

Im trying to display latest comments from all the post on a page named comments, now im able to use `<?php wp_list_comments('per_page=25', get_comments()) ?>` and it gets all the comments but when I try to use `<?php get_paginate_comments_links() ?>` nothing shows even the next and previous buttons dont show, what am i doing wrong?

This is my current code, any help is appreciated

```
<?php wp_list_comments('per_page=5', get_comments()) ?> 


              <div class="navigation">
              <?php get_paginate_comments_links(array() ?>
<?php previous_comments_link() ?>
<?php next_comments_link() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find that function in source and also not sure about your code nesting there.

There is [`paginate_comments_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links) function. Usage is around this:

```
if ( get_option( 'page_comments' ) )
    paginate_comments_links();
```

Comment: Rarst is correct, there's no such function, only `paginate_comments_links` ..(ie. minus the `get_` part)..

Comment: Also the OP might note he's got a syntax error in his pasted code above on line 5 @ `<?php get_paginate_comments_links(array() ?>`