# Aggregate comments, with pagination

Tags: pagination, comments, paginate-comments-links

I want to build a page that would display *all comments*, regardless of which post they're attached to. I also want that page to be paginated, since it'll potentially have 10,000+ comments.

---

I'm not sure how to go about it, but here are some of the functions I've studied so far:

1. [`get_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) - If no `post_id` is passed in, it'll return all comments. However, I don't see a way to paginate these (there are `offset` and `number` options to fiddle with, but that's *very* tedious to do manually).
2. [`wp_list_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) - The documentation on this is pretty bad, but [the source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1415) suggests that we can loop over all comments if used in conjunction with `get_comments`, by passing in the `get_comments` array as a second argument. This however would still use `get_comments` to actually... well, get the comments, and there seems to be no way to paginate that.
3. [`previous_comments_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_comments_link) & [`next_comments_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_comments_link) - These seem to only work in conjunction with `wp_list_comments` (with no second argument).
4. [`paginate_comments_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links) - Also looks like it only works with `wp_list_comments` (with no second argument).

---

## What I've tried:

1. Simply using the `number` argument in `get_comments`:

   ```
   $comments = get_comments(array(
       'status'    => 'approve',
       'number'    => '2'
   ));

   wp_list_comments(array(
       'callback' => 'my_rendering_function'
   ), $comments);

   paginate_comments_links();
   ```

   This does not display any pagination links.
2. The method suggested here: [Display latest comments on page with pagination](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/display-latest-comments-on-page-with-pagination)

   ```
   $comments = get_comments(array(
       'status' => 'approve'
   ));

   wp_list_comments('per_page=2', $comments);

   paginate_comments_links();
   ```

   This doesn't either work (it shows the first 2 comments, but no pagination). Also, I cringe at `get_comments` loading *all* comments into memory.

---

## Question:

How can I paginate *all* comments?

---

**P.S.** I'm using WordPress 3.4.1 & PHP 5.3.2.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the main thing that you missed is that you must have "Break comments into pages" checked in the [Settings Discussion Subpanel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Discussion_SubPanel). The pagination functions require this to be set, as do the URL rewrites.

Here's a working, complete page template to do what you're asking:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: All Comments
See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63770/aggregate-comments-with-pagination
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" role="main">

    <?php
    # The comment functions use the query var 'cpage', so we'll ensure that's set
    $page = intval( get_query_var( 'cpage' ) );
    if ( 0 == $page ) {
        $page = 1;
        set_query_var( 'cpage', $page );
    }

    # We'll do 10 comments per page...
    # Note that the 'page_comments' option in /wp-admin/options-discussion.php must be checked
    $comments_per_page = 10;
    $comments = get_comments( array( 'status' => 'approve' ) );
    ?>
    <ol start="<?php echo $comments_per_page * $page - $comments_per_page + 1 ?>">
        <?php wp_list_comments( array (
            'style' => 'ol',
            'per_page' => $comments_per_page,
            'page' => $page,
            'reverse_top_level' => false
        ), $comments ); ?>
    </ol>

    <?php # Now you can either use paginate_comments_links ... ?>
    <?php paginate_comments_links() ?>

    <?php # Or you can next/prev yourself... ?>
    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count( $comments, $comments_per_page ) > 1 ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav">
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Newer Comments' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Older Comments &rarr;' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If you didn't want to globally enable comment pagination, it's still possible, but it's a minor headache because you'll have to manually add the rewrites rules. Once you do that, you can fool WordPress into thinking that comment pagination is enabled via a simple filter,

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_page_comments', '__return_true' );
```